# RelativeLayout issue - image overlaps ScrollView

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to stick an image in the bottom of my app, and above is I have a scrollview, like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1">
        <ScrollView  android:paddingTop="180dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/scrollView12" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout4" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:paddingRight="8dip" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/cinza" android:src="@drawable/header"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I feed the scrollview dinamically, so the size of it can change. My problem is that if it grows till the end of the display, the last records goes behind my picture. I wanted it to grow just untill the picture.
Some clue on how to do this? I tried several ways, relativelayouts, linearlayouts, but sometimes the picture disappears, sometimes don't stick in the bottom...

Answer (score 4):

You should just add `android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"` for the ScrollView, and define the ImageView first, as you want it to be draw first, then the ScrollView inside the `RelativeLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/cinza"
        android:src="@drawable/header"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </ImageView>
    <ScrollView
        android:paddingTop="180dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView12"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:paddingRight="8dip"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>   
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

`RelativeLayout` is not the right chose in this case. You have to use `LinearLayout`, and the key is the `android:layout_weight` parameter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ScrollView  android:paddingTop="180dip" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout4" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:paddingRight="8dip" 
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/cinza" 
    android:src="@drawable/header"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: That totally worked, thanks a lot!!! But I didn't understood well how layout_weight works, i'll read about it.

Comment: `RelativeLayout` IS a good choice, you just have to understand how it works it. For a simple case like this, `LinearLayout` is indeed working as well, but for example, if you'd want to have two pictures  on the bottom, one near the other, you should have wrap them in a new `LinearLayout`, while with `RelativeLayout` you'd still be able to have only one parent. Read more here: [Layout Tricks: Creating Efficient Layouts](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html)

Comment: the guy answered your question and you didn't mark it as the answer?  lame.

Answer (score 0):

Give a id for scroolview then set a tag in image view android:layout_blow="id of scrollview"

Comment: I tried it and the image disappeared, it's not the answer, at least in this case