# How to stick a view at the bottom of the screen so the above part is movable?

Tags: android, android-layout

My `layout` consists of a `ScrollView` which holds everything. At some point I need to show a `View` at the bottom of the screen **on top (above) of ScrollView** (so `ScrollView` goes behind the `View`) so I could scroll the screen up and down while this `View` still be sticked to a device's screen bottom. Please advice guys how to do such a `layout`. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the scrollview to go behind the view, this can be done like this:

(partial code copy from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442911/relativelayout-issue-image-overlaps-scrollview) SO question)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1">

        <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView"  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ScrollView>

        <View android:id="@+id/bottomView" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:visibility="gone">>
        </View>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The scrollview will now expand beyond the View element.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected a question, I need this View to be placed on top of ScrollView.

Comment: Hmm what do you mean? At the bottom of the screen, on top of the scrollview? So the scrollview goes behind the View? You could do this with a RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout. If you mean you want the View at the top of the screen, above (on top) of the ScrollView, just place the view above the scrollview in the layout.

Comment: If you mean the first, then this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442911/relativelayout-issue-image-overlaps-scrollview describes your requested feature as a problem.

Comment: I mean that I need to have a View at the bottom of the screen, so scrollview goes behind the View indeed.

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot, please remove the first part, the second is what I really need.

Answer (score 1):

You could create two fragments and use the weight attribute to distribute the space. The fragment at the top would host you root scrolView and the fragment at the bottom would have the View.

Comment: No need for fragments here, i guess?

Answer (score 0):

Okay two options, first one:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/myView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/myView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This way your `ScrollView` will always be above of your `View`. But it seems like you want the ScrollView to fill the whole screen while the View "hides" some of the items of your `SV`. So check this code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <View
    android:id="@+id/myView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Better set the view to wrap_content or something like that, and make it invisible. Since you want it, to be invisible.

Comment: Normally this would be true. But in case of a `View` wrap_content will always fill the whole screen. Please don't ask me why but that's what I experienced...